# How to create a virtual directory and deploy the package in Azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How to deploy and web application with virtual directory.

How to add a virtual directory with in an existing app service. Not sure how to do it from Azure dashboard interface for an app service

I have a URL published in Azure app service, say,

https://test.mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/

I want my app to be published with in say,

https://test.mywebsite.azurewebsites.net/App1

Where App1 is my virtual directory.

Please let me know how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click Configuration->choose Path mappings->you will find the virtual applications and directories settings.

[image]

[image]

When you deploy the app to the virtual directory, remember to include the virtual directory path.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Worked as expected. Cheers

Comment: I don't seem to get anything under my path mappings tab. It only has "Mount Storage (Preview)". Not the usual path mappings I expect to see. Anyone else getting anything like this?

Comment: Me too Dessus! @Tony Ju, why do you think this might be?

Comment: I think it is caused by having app running on Linux.

Comment: Yes, this option is available only on Windows App Service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/664517/azure-web-app-missing-virtual-directory-option.html